# FreePBX How to configure FollowMe for external sip phone

Tags: asterisk

I have two SIP phones used by one person.

First phone is a softphone, used when the person is sitting in front of the computer. Let's say extension number is 200. Second phone is a hardware mobile SIP phone. It is used when the person goes to another room etc. Let's say extension number is 201.

If I call 200 extension I want both phones to be rung simultanously. It is easy to set up by FollowMe module in FreePBX, by putting 200 and 201 to Follow-Me List of 200 extension. But if I call 200 extension and the person is out of office (so his computer is turned off, softphone is offline) the 201 phone is ringing. That is wrong, because the person will not pick it up.

I want to configure it so when 200 is online 200 and 201 will ring. When 200 is offline 200 and 201 will not ring. I tried to use ringall-prim Ring Strategy, which seems to be exactly the function I need, but I don't see the difference - 201 is still ringing when 200 is offline.

Could you please advise how should I configure it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that in freepbx.

Only way is custom extensions with use of DEVICE_STATE function.

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+config+extensions.conf

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+func+device_State